# C# Interrupt/Stop a ToolClick event

Tags: c#, winforms, toolbar

On a C# form, I need to run a series of checkes when the user selects save from the tool menu. If one of these checks fail, the save procedure needs to be stopped. Here is the current code:

```
private static void baseToolbarsManager_ToolClick(object sender, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.ToolClickEventArgs args)
{
     if (args.Tool.Key == "SaveTool")
     {
             if (tbxJob == "")
             {
                  MessageBox.Show("Error: No job was entered");
                  //Stop the save event from happening here
             }
      }
}
```

Comment: Does adding "return;" statement after messagebox fix your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Where does your Save method get called from?  Why not just add the `if (tbxJob == "")` check to the Save method?  Or maybe have it check some boolean value for whether or not to cancel the save operation?

I don't believe there is anything you can put in the method you posted to cancel the operation, you'd have to put the cancel check before the call to Save, or put it within the Save method itself.

Comment: Im adding a form to an existing application wich I have limited control. I don't have access to change the save method. My only choice is to catch it before the actual save method is called.

Comment: Is there a BeforeToolClick event which has event args with a Cancel property?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you need to prevent an event to be called. So a solution could be inherit that control class and override the `OnToolClick()` method:

```
private override void OnToolClick(ToolClickEventArgs e){
    if (e.Tool.Key == "SaveTool"){
         if (tbxJob == "")
             MessageBox.Show("Error: No job was entered");
             //Stop the save event from happening here
         else
             base.OnToolClick(e);
    }
}
```